# Wordpress 5.0 Remove Discussion metabox

Tags: php, wordpress

in previous versions of Wordpress, it was relatively easy to remove metaboxes from certain post types. In Wp 5.0.2, it doesn't seem so straight forward. I would like to remove the 'Discussion' metabox in the right-hand sidebar, however the below is not working?

```
function remove_post_custom_fields() {
    remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv', 'post', 'side' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_post_custom_fields' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make use of the function called remove meta box.

```
<?php
add_action( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'acme_remove_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );

function acme_remove_meta_boxes( $hidden, $screen ) {
    if ( 'acme_post_type' == $screen->id ) {
        $hidden = array(
            'acme_post_type_categorydiv',
            'authordiv',
            'postexcerpt',
            'slugdiv'
            );

    }
    return $hidden;    
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @kinnariprajapati - unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working? 

function remove_meta_boxes( $hidden, $screen ) {
    if ( 'post' == $screen->id ) {
        $hidden = array(
            'commentstatusdiv',
            'authordiv',
            'postexcerpt',
            'slugdiv'
            );

    }
    return $hidden;    
}
add_action( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'remove_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );

Comment: You can try this

Comment: What should I try?

Comment: sorry see above -@dungey_140

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `default_hidden_meta_boxes` and it works great. You don't have to specify other parameters like $context like you have to do with `remove_meta_box`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
function remove_my_post_metaboxes() {
remove_meta_box( 'authordiv','post','normal' ); // Author Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv','post','normal' ); // Comments Status Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv','post','normal' ); // Comments Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'postcustom','post','normal' ); // Custom Fields Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt','post','normal' ); // Excerpt Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'revisionsdiv','post','normal' ); // Revisions Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'slugdiv','post','normal' ); // Slug Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv','post','normal' ); // Trackback Metabox
}
add_action('admin_menu','remove_my_post_metaboxes');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Does the code need updating for WP5?

Comment: Any further suggestions @kinnariprajapati?

Comment: This worked on my custom post type. You could use CSS and jQuery/javascript to remove it. Not as ideal as it will be available in the "view code" but it solves the visibility problem.